# "Highcarts is not defined error" after installing highcharts

Tags: typescript, npm, charts, highcharts, angular5

I am implementing `Highcharts` in angular5 using `ng2-highcharts` npm package. But it is giving error that highcharts is not defined.

I have an angular5 project in which i am implementing Highcharts and using "angular2-highcharts" npm package. But it is giving an error

`Highcharts is not defined at new AppComponent`

Here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvxq6w

I am implementing this example. This should be like this

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/spline/

Comment: did you import highchat in your component ?

Comment: Can you provide the link for the mentioned library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing few things

1. You are missing import `npm i angular2-highcharts`
2. The way you are implementing is wrong you need to define the `chart` component which is nicely explained in the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#usage), like this

and instead of defining global variable you need to pass the options

```
 this.options= {

      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },

      title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 2, 10],
        type: 'spline',
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmedyy)

Comment: actually i am making a stadalone component for graph. So that i can call that graph component in another module. So should i import all dependencies to app.module.ts and also in module in which we will use that graph component?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari the package it self provides the reusable component, why to create new wheel when you already have that?

Comment: Its my requirement i have to do other tasks too in that graph component. Can you edit your example and can make graph standalone component which can be call in any other module's component?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari you can add the same code in graph component export that component to the module and import into another module, this way you can have the same component working with other modules too. but in that modules you need to have the high charts definition added. moreover you need to learn about sharable modules for this requirement.

Comment: thanx i  fixed an issue.

Comment: can you tell me how to change theme of highcharts spline graph?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari it should be in the package you need to explore it